# Set lightning input in a child component based on parent component onChange event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events, lightning-inputfield

I am implementing simple Contact create/edit form and I have problems with automatic setting of one field (*consbp*) based on an entry in different field (AccountID).
The main component (`contactCreate.cmp`) needs to register an event which is firing up when *Account ID* field is changed, and a child component (`consbpAutoFill.cmp`) will handle that event and set value in the field *consbp*.

Event:

```js
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="editAccountEvent">
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

Main component `contactCreate.cmp` is using a *recordEditForm* for AccountID and has `onchange` call to JS controller function. The component also has the child component for *consbp* field:

```js
<aura:component controller="contactController">

    <!-- Account ID edit Event-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="editAccount" type="c:editAccountEvent"/>

     <!-- Lookup for Account object-->
     <lightning:recordEditForm class="slds-m-around_small"
                                          aura:id="recordViewForm"
                                          objectApiName="Contact">

           <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" value="{!v.contact.AccountId}" onchange="{!c.autoConsBP}"/>
     </lightning:recordEditForm>

     <!-- Child component to auto fill -->
     <c:consbpAutoFill/>
</aura:component>
```

`contactCreateController.js` has a function which calls the *editAccountEvent* (AccountId is an array because of recordEditForm):

```js
autoConsBP: function (component, event, helper) {
        var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("editAccount");
        cmpEvent.setParams({
            "accountId": component.get("v.contact.AccountId")[0]
        });
        cmpEvent.fire();
    }
```

The child component `consbpAutoFill.cmp` has a handler defined for the **editAccountEvent**:

```js
<aura:component description="consbpAutoFill" controller="contactController">

    <aura:attribute name="consBP" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="editAccount" event="c:editAccountEvent" action="{!c.autoFillConsbp}"/>

    <lightning:input class="slds-m-around_small" required="true" label="Cons BP"
                     placeholder="consbp" type="text" variant="standard"
                     aura:id="consBP" value="{!v.consBP}" disabled="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

The last part is the child component JS controller (*consbpAutoFillController.js*):

```js
    autoFillConsbp: function (component, event, helper) {
        //Just print id for now
        var accountId = event.getParam("accountId");
        console.log("Account ID: " + accountId);
    }
```

When I do `console.log()` of *AccountId* in main component, it is correctly being set and the event seems to fire up, but nothing is happening after that.
The whole logic of auto fill was working as long as the whole form was in `contactCreate` component but I need to seperate *consbp* field into seperate component and handle changes using events. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Application event handling musn't specify a name for the event. The event is handled through its type. You should remove the name attribute on the aura:handler.

Comment: @MartinLezer would you mind adding it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an incorrect sintax for application events:

```
var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("editAccount");
    cmpEvent.setParams({
        "accountId": component.get("v.contact.AccountId")[0]
    });
    cmpEvent.fire();
```

When you have an Application Event, the correct syntax is:

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:appEvent");
appEvent.fire();
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_fire.htm)

Comment: Removing the name attribute from aura:handler and changing the syntax of firing up an Application Event solved the issue - I was able to correctly send the event, thanks!

Comment: @UOMan one more thing when you want to call a method on a child component use `aura:method` that enables you to directly call a method in a component’s client-side controller instead of firing and handling an event.